# Trouble with Proxy Configuration and Websocket

Tags: apache, websocket, proxy, reverse-proxy

Running CentOS with WHM/cPanel.  Running a third party BI Tool that we recently opened to customers.  It runs on port 8080 and had many problems with customers and the port.  Tried to set up a proxy to allow users to hit port 80.  Everything works except the WebSocket.  Works on port 8080 but not 80.

Error:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://test.titandash.com/vs-events/831/dot3dqaq/websocket' failed:
>   Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

**WS URLs:**

- Not Working: ws://test.titandash.com/vs-events/978/sjnprvmw/websocket
- Working: ws://titandash.com:8080/vs-events/526/b2ofnbsz/websocket

**Current Conf.d Include**

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
<VirtualHost 192.249.120.188:80>
        ServerName test.titandash.com
        ServerAdmin ccole@shiptsg.com
        ProxyPreserveHost Off
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPass / http://titandash.com:8080/ upgrade=WebSocket
        ProxyPass "/vs-events" "http://titandash.com:8080/vs-events" upgrade=WebSocket
        ProxyPassReverse / http://titandash.com:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

If you are still using the 000-default.conf, put your virtual host configuration in there, not in config.d

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.titandash.com
    ServerAdmin ccole@shiptsg.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass "/vs-events/" "ws://[enterbackendserver]:8080/vs-events"
</VirtualHost>
```

Then run these in command line:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy

sudo a2enmod proxy_http

sudo a2enmod proxy_wstunnel

sudo systemctl restart apache2
```